# Nmap showing different open ports every few seconds

Tags: network, nmap, ports, network-scanners, aws

I'm running Nmap on an Amazon Web Services EC2 instance but between runs just a couple seconds apart, I'm getting new results. Is this normal? I'm seeing open ports then they don't show.

I'm running this command connected through SSH (Mac OSX):

```
nmap -p 0-65535 127.0.0.1
```

Results:

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-05 23:07 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00015s latency).
Not shown: 65533 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
39341/tcp open  unknown
47684/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.89 seconds
user@ip-xx-x-x-xxx:~$ nmap -p 0-65535 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-05 23:07 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00015s latency).
Not shown: 65535 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.89 seconds
user@ip-xx-x-x-xxx:~$ nmap -p 0-65535 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-05 23:07 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00015s latency).
Not shown: 65534 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
53831/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.88 seconds
```